# DSQUERY Parameters

Tags: command-line-arguments

I love the examples on http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/DSquery_user.htm but some additional should be helpful:

- Cn with space in the name
- Ou with the space in it
- Etc…

I tried several times and always getting no error but no results as well
e.g.:

```
dsquery * -attr "cn" -filter "(&(operatingSystem=*server*)(member='cn=Monday 10AM',ou=Server Security Groups,ou=MITS Servers,dc=ad,dc=xxxxxxx,dc=xxxx,dc=edu))" >>
```

c:\test\test.txt

or

```
C:\Users\rmppqx>dsquery * -attr "cn" -filter "(&(operatingSystem=*server*)(member=cn=Monday*,ou=Server Security Groups,ou=MITS Servers,dc=ad,dc=xxxxxxr,dc=xxxx,dc=edu))" >> c:\test\test.txt
```

Any idea why the result file is always empty!!!

Thanks,
Dom

Answer (score 1):

Your 1st example didn't work because spaces do not need to be specially quoted in LDAP filters (in fact, you already have an OU with spaces in its name), so it was trying to find an attribute `'cn` with the value `Monday 10AM'`.

For example:

```
-filter "(&(operatingSystem=…)(member=cn=Monday 10AM,ou=Server Security Groups,…))"
```

The only characters that need quoting within a filter are:

```
( → \28
) → \29
* → \2a
\ → \5c
```

For example, to find `cn=Monday (10AM),ou=…` you would use `(member=cn=Monday \2810AM\29,ou=…)`.

---

Your 2nd example didn't work because the `member` attribute doesn't support wildcard matching.